# Changing entire background color of table cell in Django Admin

Tags: python, html, django, django-admin

I'm trying to color an entire Django Table Cell and this following code only colorizes the text in the Django Admin and not the ENTIRE table cell. What is currently looks like:

[image]

Here's the current code

```
class Student(models.Model):

    def city_and_zip(self):
        if self.city_zip:
            cell_html = '<div style = "background-color:#e6f2ff;">%s</div>'
        else:
            cell_html = '<div>%s</div>'

        return cell_html % self.city_zip

    city_and_zip.allow_tags = True
```

Again, it colorizes it properly... but only to some extent. I would like to color the entire cell. Changing div to th doesn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare list_display for `modelAdmin`, `td` element wich consist this field has css-class like `field-'list_display_name'`. I your case it will `field-city_and_zip`.
So you can add css selectors for this class. Django provides many solutions for this approach. Here is one:

```
class StudentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    @property
    def media(self):
        media = super(ProductAdmin, self).media
        css = {
            "all": (
                "css/your.css",
            )
        }
        media.add_css(css)
        return media
```

In other hand you can write `class Media` in your admin model:

```
class StudentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    class Media:
        css = {"all":("css/your.css",)}
```

Then put this css file in your static path and write selectors:

```
.field-city_and_zip {
     background-color: #e6f2ff;
}
```

And it should work like you need. Also you can put css directly in admin base template
[more information about admin page](http://admin%20documentation)

Answer (score 1):

You can change admin css assets in two ways:

1. **Model level:** Add required css files to your admin model.

   ```
   class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
       class Media:
           js = ('js/admin/my_own_admin.js',)    
           css = {
               'all': ('css/admin/my_own_admin.css',)
           }
   ```
2. **Template level:** If you want to change the appearance of the admin in general you should override admin templates. This is covered in details here: [Overriding admin templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates).

Sometimes you can just extend the original admin file and then overwrite a block like `{% block extrastyle %}{% endblock %}` in [django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html) as an example.